# tkinter rowspan has no effect

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

    class Home(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.geometry('1200x800')
            self.txt = tk.StringVar()
            self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.home_frame = tk.Frame(self)
            self.home_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
            self.home_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.home_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.fileEntry = tk.Entry(self.home_frame, width=100, textvariable=self.txt).grid(row=0, column=0,  sticky='sn')
            self.btn = tk.Button(self.home_frame, text='choose directory', height=1, command=self.DirDialog).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

now for fileEntry adding rowspan=2 has no effect at all what is wrong?

Comment: Since you only have one row, what do you expect to accomplish by having it span two rows? Are you trying to make the entry taller? Entry widgets can only ever have a single line of text. I don't understand what you think spanning an empty row should do.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was trying to control each widget width in manner similar to Bootstrap CSS grid. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your widget only has one row, so spanning two rows will appear just like spanning a single row. Empty rows have a height of zero.

Comment: @Brayan Oakley sorry I am totally new to tkinter so would you explain more? I did not understand and if you may kindly suggest soloution

Comment: @mark the solution is to add another widget and you will see you have in fact spanned two rows